# How do I install django-extensions and its dependancies without ever using the internet?

Tags: python, django, setup.py, django-extensions

I am looking to install django-extensions and its dependancies (particularly six) without ever hitting the internet. I have the tarballs for both django-extensions and six, so am able to install offline. However, I see in my logs that pip firsts tries to find six on pypi before checking locally. Instead, I want to force the installer to never check pypi.

Log output (this is before I downloaded the six tarball, so please ignore the local packages error)

> Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.2.5-py2.7.egg
>
> Processing dependencies for django-extensions==1.2.5
>
> Searching for six
>
> Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/six/
>
> Download error: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution -- Some packages may not be found!
>
> Couldn't find index page for 'six' (maybe misspelled?)
>
> Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
>
> Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
>
> Download error: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution -- Some packages may not be found!
>
> No local packages or download links found for six

Comment: First step: prepare your stone tablet  ;-)

Comment: Why are you using pip if you aren't going to use the internet? Just install them via their `setup.py` scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U may try:

1)  Extract the tarballs and execute **python setup.py install** in the extracted  directories.

2) Or if u want to use pip insistently, first u must download the pip package: **pip install --download /temp_download_dir package_name==version**  ("==version" is optional) and u may install the pip package with **pip install --no-index --find-links /temp_download_dir package_name**

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer to your question is to pass the `--no-index` option to `pip`, which will avoid checking the index for packages.

You really need to setup a local `pypi` mirror and just point `pip` to that mirror. This is what I do at work where machines are restricted from the Internet. It can get a bit complicated because it requires setting up of a web server (see [`pypiserver`](https://github.com/schmir/pypiserver) and [this blog](http://aboutsimon.com/2012/02/24/create-a-local-pypi-mirror/) which talks about setting up mirrors as per [pep-381](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0381/)).

If that's not an option for you, the easiest way to do this is to use [`basket`](http://pythonhosted.org/Basket/). Once you install it (using `pip`), just ask it to download packages:

```
$ basket init # initialize the directory
Repository has been created: ~/.basket
$ basket download django-extensions # this will download any dependencies as well
```

Then, move the `~/.basket` directory to your machine without Internet, and run:

```
pip install --no-index -f file:///path/to/.basket django-extensions
```